# Undefined reference to wgl -functions

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a OpenGL context through windows API.
Everything else is fine for now, but I just can't figure out how to link up with right library to get access to wgl.. functions.

I use MinGW to compile. and a make file.
I have tried to link against: 
-lmingw32 -mwindows -lgdi32 -lopengl32
with no luck to fix the problem.

I am #including windows.h and gl.h, but neither of them contain wgl functions?
What am I missing?

Below is my WM_CREATE event portion of the code (That's the only thing that matter for this).

```
    case WM_CREATE:
    {   PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
            1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,            //The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
            32,                        //Colordepth of the framebuffer.
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            24,                        //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
            8,                        //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
            0,                        //Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
            0,
            0, 0, 0
        };

        // Get current handle to device context.
        HDC hDc = GetDC(hWnd);

        // Generate pixel format.
        int wPf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDc, &pfd);

        // Set pixel format.
        SetPixelFormat(hDc, wPf, &pfd);

        // OpenGL context
        HGLRC GLc = wglCreateContext(hDc);

        // Make it current.
        wglMakeCurrent(hDc, GLc);

        break;
    }
```

Here is my make file:

```
CXX = g++
SRC = engine.cpp os.cpp
DST = build/engine.exe
PATHS = -L c:\MinGW\lib -I c:\MinGW\include
FLAGS = -mwindows
LIBS = -lmingw32 -opengl32

$(DST): $(SRC)
    $(CXX) -o $(DST) $(FLAGS) $(PATHS) $(SRC) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Order of libraries passed to the linker matter. Please show the full linker invocation.

Comment: I use the exact order which I wrote in my post. Mentioned in MinGW portion.

Comment: Yes, but that's only half the story. The whole linker invocation matters; that means we also have to see how and where you pass the to be linked object files (or if you compiling directly to executable) where in the line you have the source files.

Comment: Also `-mwindows` doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I remove -mwindows I get undefined reference to "ChoosePixelFormat@8" if I add it, I don't get that error anymore.

Comment: Okay `-mwindows` is not a library, but a linker flag, that instructs MinGW to create a executable that does *not* create a console window upon launch and launches off from `WinMain` instead of `main`.

Comment: Yes that much I somewhat understand, so that did not have an effect on my original issue :)

Comment: Yes, you should put it into `FLAGS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

> ```
> $(DST): $(SRC)
>     $(COMPILER) $(FLAGS) $(PATHS) $(LIBS) -o $(DST) $(SRC)
> ```

In general with the old style GNU linker, symbols must be introduced in files coming *after* the files that reference them. You have your *source* files at the very last, which usually messes up linking. Try reordering this way:

```
$(DST): $(SRC)
    $(CXX) -o $(DST) $(FLAGS) $(PATHS) $(SRC) $(LIBS)
```

BTW: We never call a variable "COMPILER" in makefiles, because there might be a number of difference compilers being used for a single project. The variable holding the C++ compiler executable name is usually called `CXX` (and C compilers are named by the variable `CC` in Makefiles).

Comment: Thank you for the makefile tip. I am aware of the variable use in makefiles. I just put it like that for now just for my own purposes (studying so that my mind learns to visualize them where what is). 

Sadly those fixes didn't have an effect on the wgl issue :(